# How to adjust a jQuery function property value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

First of all, I'm pretty new to jQuery but with the help of http://css-tricks.com/examples/Circulate/ I managed to figure out how to create ellipses in my code.
Here's the thing though, I want to create an input field/text box for users to type in their own "speed" value (which is now set at "500") and then click a submit button to start the ellipse.

```
 $("#ball").circulate({
            speed: 500,
            height: 500,
            width: 200,
            loop: true,
            zIndexValues: [1, 1, 1, 1]
        });
```

I figured out the submit button part, but I keep running in circles when it comes to finding a way for a visitor of my website to manually input the "speed". I would be much obliged if someone could point me in the right direction/could give me a starting point.

Comment: Get the speed from the input and set it as a variable, then, in your function, replace the number with the variable.

Comment: Could you provide some part of your html? and how are you calling this procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    var userSpeed = +$('#inputBox').val();
      if (!userSpeed) {userSpeed == 500};
    $("#ball").circulate({
                speed: userSpeed,
                height: 500,
                width: 200,
                loop: true,
                zIndexValues: [1, 1, 1, 1]
            });
});
```

Then, when the user clicks on the submit button, your code gets the new value and sets the speed for the function.  If the user clicks the button without having entered a number, a default speed is used.

Comment: Thank you as well for your help, this has definitely put me on the right track. I'm still a bit stuck though and created a jsFiddle if you feel like taking a look (the input value doesn't seem to change the speed..only when I manually set a speed in the code myself it would appear to work). http://jsfiddle.net/Rorschach_/qxcn4zxc/10/

Comment: Sorry - there was a typo in my answer (I've edited it above) - note the `+` in the second line.  `val()` returns a string - and you want a number.  It should work now.  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qxcn4zxc/11/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .val() function to get the value from an input and then use it to set the speed.

```
var input = $("#YOUR_INPUT_ID");
$("#ball").circulate({
        speed: input.val(),
        height: 500,
        width: 200,
        loop: true,
        zIndexValues: [1, 1, 1, 1]
});
```

Comment: Thanks to to you (both) I'm finally on the right track. Unfortunately I've been working on it all day, but I'm still somewhat stuck. I've created a jsFiddle though, perhaps you'd be willing to take a look? It's right here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rorschach_/qxcn4zxc/10/ While the 'launch' button does make the ball move in an arc (changed that instead of ellipse because that's what I really wanted) it won't change to the speed typed into the input box. I've looked up the documentation about .val() and input tags but I can't quite put my finger on where things go wrong.